# Replace last occurrence of an HEX file - Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm building a script in bash that edits a binary file. I managed how to achieve first occurrence replace and all occurrences replace but i cannot manage how to replace the last occurrence.

The script has to replace F8 byte with F0.

This is the code for ALL and FIRST:

ALL

```
perl -pe 's/\x{F8}/\x{F0}/g' < CS.midi > CSnew.midi
```

FIRST

```
perl -pe 's/\x{F8}/\x{F0}/' < CS.midi > CSnew.midi
```

Any suggestions for replace the last occurrence of F8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code to change the first is incorrect. You are reading the file a line at a time, and it changes the first *of each line*. This means is changes the first, and the first after each LF (0x0A).

`-0777` will cause the entire file to be treated as one line.

```sh
perl -0777pe's/\xF8/\xF0/g'        # All
perl -0777pe's/\xF8/\xF0/'         # First
perl -0777pe's/^.*\K\xF8/\xF0/s'   # Last
```

Comment: yooo! This is working!! I added "-i" argument to edit file in place also!! thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions isn't even needed:

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 'substr $_, rindex($_, "\xF8"), 1, "\xF0"' CS.midi > CSnew.midi
```

reads the entire file, and replaces the last occurrence of the matching byte.